# Prxparse Sas equivalent in Python/Pyspark

Tags: python, sql, pyspark, sas

i just wanted to know if there was a simple equivalent of prxparse (SAS) in Python or Pyspark.

Comment: Please describe how are you using *prxparse (SAS)* currently and what you want to achieve in *Python or Pyspark*

Comment: check out the regex functions available in pandas and pyspark -- there aren't any direct equivalents that I know of, but they have their own functions that would do similar stuff with hacks

Comment: `prxparse` is a function to return an ID that corresponds to a regular expression that can be used in other regex functions. It's basically a regex compiler. Python has plenty of regex abilities that are equivalent.

Comment: Try `re.compile ()`